# Oauth2 Get access_token from UBER

Tags: java, post, oauth, uber-api

I'm trying to convert the authorization code to access token and I get "BAD REQUEST" 
(400) and empty response body.

Here is my code:

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    PostMethod post = new PostMethod("https://login.uber.com/oauth/token");

    post.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", URLEncoder.encode("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "UTF-8"));

    post.setParameter("grant_type",URLEncoder.encode("authorization_code", "UTF-8"));
    post.setParameter("client_id",URLEncoder.encode("mq_LxaL0P-Kn8Wq3TmuhztFkOhISxReq", "UTF-8"));
    post.setParameter("client_secret",URLEncoder.encode("MY_SECRET", "UTF-8"));
    post.setParameter("redirect_uri",URLEncoder.encode("https://jfpmrvbais.localtunnel.me/TaxyNow/webresources/generic", "UTF-8"));
    post.setParameter("code", URLEncoder.encode("S9UOTmXLGp20GF6y7TFf9pw5Pkekrl", "UTF-8"));


    client.executeMethod(post);
    String responseBody = post.getResponseBodyAsString();
    String statusCode= post.getStatusText();
```

UBER relevant [docs](https://developer.uber.com/v1/auth/).

I'm looking for a solution for two days. In addition I checked all the similar questions in stackoverflow and I found nothing.

Many thanks

**EDIT:**
Problem solved , the following is the working code:

```
       HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    PostMethod post = new PostMethod("https://login.uber.com/oauth/token");
    post.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    post.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    post.setParameter("client_secret",MY_SECRET);
    post.setParameter("client_id",clientId);
    post.setParameter("grant_type", "authorization_code");
    post.setParameter("redirect_uri", REDIRECT_URL);
    post.setParameter("code", code);
```

One important thing:
They ask you to insert the same redirect_url you inserted in the previous request.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a library to handle OAuth ? 
The doc says "We recommend that you use a pre-built library to perform grant and token exchanges" https://developer.uber.com/v1/auth/ . 
I am also facing some issues, but at least i don't get a 400 back :-).

Matt

Comment: Yes I tried with google library.. finally I solved it see the Edit question.